# Java 6 doesn't work on OS 10.6.8

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, java

i don't understand and need some help: java doesn't work anymore for a few months and i don't know why.

I have installed the latest version from apple, actually the 1.6.0_45-b06-451 on my imac 21,5" of middle 2010 and after checking the security system option and enabled the firefox plugin, i tried in safari and Chrome. Also tried with 32 and 64 bits kernel...

Finally i checked the XProtect.meta.plist to see the version limit allowed.
When i check on java.com it seem disabled or not installed, but on other sites it worked fine, like [here](http://stone-prod.com/images/Test_Java.htm) (or javatester.org for examples)

What can i do for use without issues like i did before ?
Thanks a lot for any help...

Comment: For information, my 1st ligne "hello everybody" disappeared even after trying editing...

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! As per the [site's guidelines](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), greetings and signatures are not considered acceptable behavior, so the site automatically removes such things from questions and answers to reduce noise.

Answer (score -1):

If you install OSX Mavericks via the app store, Java will stay up to date & working.

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast ! But i can't download it for the moment, very bad connexion.
I also need to keep my Snow Leopard for software's compatibilities (and a little afraid of the ressources needed)